# Web traffic analysis of third-party sites

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, search, visitors

Is there any way we can know how many people landed on an article page of a third-party site directly or by searching from Google?

Answer (score 1):

Besides asking, the only way you're going to get this information is if the site chooses to expose it in some way. Some just have something along the lines of "viewed xxx times" right on the site. Others make at least some of their stats packages public(here's [Gizmodo's Sitemeter info](http://www.sitemeter.com/?a=stats&s=s15gizmodo&r=0)), but on the whole this is going to be very rare.

Answer (score 0):

**( I donno if its legal or not )**

you  have to host an image, on a server which you have access to logs ..Then use that image on the third party article site.
then you can track the guys who have viewed the image used in the third party article site .